# Seek clarity on regex with $ and \Z

Tags: python, regex

There is wee confusion between $ and \Z in regex. I understand the underlying concept,
\Z matches the end of the string regardless of the multiline mode where as
$ matches end of the string or just before "\n" in multiline mode.

```
import re
items = ['lovely', '1\dentist', '2 lonely', 'eden', 'fly\n', 'dent']

# res = [e for e in items if re.search(r'\Aden|ly\Z', e)]
t = re.compile(r"^den|ly$")
res = [e for e in items if  t.search(e)]
print(res)
res = ['lovely', '2 lonely', 'fly\n', 'dent']
```

Why am I matching "fly\n", It ends with "\n" so isn't it suppose to ignore it where as `r"^den|ly\Z"` get me the desired result.

Comment: "$ Matches the end of the string or just before the newline at the end of the string, and in MULTILINE mode also matches before a newline." The word "also" is important - so "before a newline" is true in both cases.

Answer (score 0):

Note the python documentation for the [`$` special character](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#index-2):

> Matches the end of the string or *just before the newline at the end of the string* [emphasis added] […]

In `"fly\n"`, the newline is at the end of the string, so '$' can match just before it. If instead the string were `"fly\n\n"`, then the regex would fail.